# Use iAd JS framework to create a web app?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, iad

do you think it would be possible (**legally**) to use the [iAd JS framework](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/appstore/iad/) (the one that is provided for the developers for creating the ads) to **create the whole iOS web application itself**?

I've tried reading some legalese (*iAd Network Contract*) but it doesn't mention about in what ways I'm allowed to use their JavaScript framework.

It has so many pre-implemented controls and UI eyecandy that it would be a shame if the framework usage was restricted to implementing advertising only :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you download and install the iAd JS Developer SDK, you are presented with a license agreement as part of the installer (look for the Software License Agreement step).

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to post the text of that agreement here, but read section 2.1 carefully.  It explicitly states that iAd JS is only for use in crafting rich media ads for the iAd platform, and that you are not allowed to use or distribute the framework for any other purpose.  This seems to indicate that, for now, you can only use this for designing iAds.

Comment: Yup, you're right. Forgot to check the installer for the license, my bad.

Comment: Good find! I have been looking for this also! N

Comment: Wow somebody actually read the license agreement. +1 for the sheer effort!

Answer (score 1):

You should file a bug at https://bugreport.apple.com/ to let Apple know that you're interested in using iAd JS outside of the iAd network.

Answer (score 0):

I think if Apple wanted to restrict its usage it probably would have said so in the license agreement. They have released a framework called [PastryKit](http://www.nxfx.com/blog/iphone-development/apples-pastry-kit-iphone-javascript-toolkit/) which might be worth taking a look at; the internals may even be quite similar to iAd.js.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

The problem is that I can't find **any** license for iAd JS framework (the code itself, not the network).

Apple themselves **haven't** released PastryKit in any way. Your link points to a post where some guys "beautifulized" a bunch of JS/CSS resources used in the iPhone User Manual, however, that code is still owned by Apple, and there's no notice (license or anything) about whether someone else can use it.